# Background: transparent does not work

Tags: css, background

I try to use background-color transparent for my task (can see in image) , but its not useful . Background-transparent do nothing , its show li's background-color .

I try many ways but its not working . What can i do ?

Thanks in advance .

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>

   <span class="left-arrow-winners"></span>
   <span class="right-arrow-winners" ></span>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 12px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75);
    transition: all 250ms;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.left-arrow-winners , 
.right-arrow-winners {
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 18px/32px icomoon;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
}

.left-arrow-winners {
    left: 0
}

.right-arrow-winners {
    right: 0
}

.left-arrow-winners:before {
    content: "\e92a";
}

.right-arrow-winners:before {
    content: "\e92b";
}
```

Comment: Is the red square how you want it to look, or how it looks with you using background transparent?

Comment: Should the transparency be applied when you hover the list item?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke its my final destination :)

Comment: @Gerard , no , its for last visible element of my carusel , arrows are navigations for carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be you have not set the transparency style in the correct html tag.
As you said, after applying transparency, you are getting background color of li's tag, so try to set transparency in the li tag.

**Note** that if we apply transparency in any element, it is obvious that the particular DOM element's background color gets transparent and we can see the background color of its parent element(in your case, the parent element is li).

To make the **gradient as transparent**, set the `opacity` which is 4th parameter of rgba() to 0, which is marked as bold letter here,

background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, **0**) 75%);

In the below example, I tried to show 2 ways, might be one which you want.

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 12px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75);
    transition: all 250ms;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.transparentBackground{
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
}

body{
  background:linear-gradient(to right, red 0, yellow 75%);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(to right, red 0, yellow 75%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(to right, red 0, yellow 75%);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(to right, red 0, yellow 75%);
}

.transparentBackground1{
background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="menu-content">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="transparentBackground"><a href="#">Link 3  &nbsp;&nbsp;>></a></li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <ul class="menu-content">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="transparentBackground1"><a href="#">>></a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks , but its not solution for my task

Comment: What you exactly want is not clear in the ques. Could you please elaborate more, when and where you want the transparent background so that I will update my answer

Comment: I need to add linear-background  on the end of <ul> (:after maybe). or on the end of .arrow  .

Comment: I have updated the my answer and shown 2 ways to do that. If that's not the answer you want, please  share your html and css.

Comment: Its good way, but in my case background transparent not a color (in your example you use from rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) 0 to rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 75% , ) , I need from rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75) to transparent (image background)

Comment: very simple, just need to set the opacity 0. I have updated my code,

Answer (score 0):

This can be your best friend: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Is this what you were looking for?

White - fade to transparent background?

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 12px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: rgba(230, 229, 220, 0.75);
    transition: all 250ms;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
li{
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+51,7db9e8+100&0.9+51,0.01+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,0.01) 100%); 
/* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0.01) 100%); 
/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0.01) 100%); 
/* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e6ffffff', endColorstr='#037db9e8',GradientType=1 ); 
/* IE6-9 */
}

.left-arrow-winners , 
.right-arrow-winners {
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 18px/32px icomoon;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
}

.left-arrow-winners {
    left: 0
}

.right-arrow-winners {
    right: 0
}

.left-arrow-winners:before {
    content: "\e92a";
}

.right-arrow-winners:before {
    content: "\e92b";
}
div{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>

   <span class="left-arrow-winners"></span>
   <span class="right-arrow-winners" ></span>
<div>
```